# Can i transfer one MySQL database without stoping MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, database, administration

detailed: I have some MySQL databases,for example:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDB1;
CREATE DATABASE MyDB2;
CREATE DATABASE MyDB3;
CREATE DATABASE MyDB4;
```

each one is databased used by another client. **MyDB1** started to **use too much resources** and needs dedicated server. I need to transfer **only one** database(its ok if that database will be unavailable(better if it will be available all time) other databases should be available all time. Is free version of MySQL enough?
Each database size is near 5 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a tool called myqslhotcopy, which is desigend to dump a running database. It does however use lock_table, but it is supposed to be a faster way than mysqldump.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlhotcopy.html

My suggestion would be to dump the database during non peak hours and use scp/rsync to move it to a desired server.

Another approach is to use mysqldump as Bitmap has suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqldump to backup the database you want to transfer. On Unix or Linux enviroment do something like:

```
mysqldump -u my_username -p name_of_database_to_transfer > scp username_on_remote_machine@IP_address_of_remote_machine:/location_to_save_on_remote/backup.sql
```

On Windows platform, share the drive of the machine to transfer to and mysqldump onto the share.

Alternatively dump onto usb and transfer to the allocated machine. When the file is on the machine, execute the script through any mysql client or use mysqldump again to restore back to the database.

This means on the new machine, you create an empty database with the same name as the one backed up, and restore the script to push the data and tables back to existence.

Eg. `mysqldump -u your_username -p database_name < backup.sql`.

Hope this helps else pardon me if I didnt understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

i think mysqldump will lock your tables. I'd recommend something like: http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/ that will let you backup your database in a "hot copy" fashion, transfer the files via the network and be ready to operate in a few minutes. other solution is to configure the mysql in replication. so the slave node will replicate the master data. you can then shutdown the master server safely